# How do I secure a system where a handheld connects to a SQL database via JDBC?

Tags: sql, sql-server, flutter, sql-server-2019

I am developing a Flutter app and to save on development time I am using a Flutter package called [sql_conn](https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn). This uses a JDBC driver to connect to a SQL database. However, I am seeing online that this setup isn't recommended for a production app because of the risk of malicious SQL statements being run against the database.

My app is not public facing. It will run on an internal company network and the devices will not be allowed to be taken offsite. In addition to this, every request sent to the database looks like the example below, so I would look into finding a way to sanitize user inputs/parametrizing the query.

```
var res = await SqlConn.readData("declare @LoginState bit declare @Status nvarchar(4000) exec spHandheldLogin '$username', '$password', @LoginState output, @Status output");
```

Each user would have their own SQL login and each login would be locked down such that they can only execute ~10 existing stored procedures in the database.

To me, this seems pretty safe. Is there anything else I can do to further strengthen security? Or am I crazy for trying to implement this and should instead use a middleman web server?

Comment: It's a really bad idea to allow non-server devices to directly connect to your database. You are opening your entire database to any hacker who can inspect the app and retrieve the username/pass there. You should create a middle tier app (probably exposing a REST API) so the handheld can connect to it instead. This middle tier can have full access to the database.

Comment: Since that package is only available for Android, what's the advantage here of using Flutter? I think the point here is that your app is not a production app - in the normal sense of that phrase. Check with your CISO whether it meets you company's policies.

Comment: @TheImpaler The only risks I see are 1. someone taking a device offsite/reverse engineering it to change the source code and 2. our sa password being leaked.

Comment: @RichardHeap Flutter is easier to develop with than native Kotlin and we only need this to run on Android devices anyway.

Comment: Could someone explain how a web server is safer? Is it still possible to do SQL injection via a web server?